# Remove items (sublists) from nested list based on comparison of their elements

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-lists

first post here, so I hope I 'm not duplicating any questions (I checked, though).

Here's the deal:

I have a list, containing 4 element sublists, e.g. `[[10,1,3,6],[22,3,5,7],[2,1,4,7],[44,3,1,0]]`

What I want to do is:

1) Remove all elements having a fourth subelement equal to zero e.g `[44,3,1,0]` (the easy part)

2) Remove items that have the same second element,keeping only the ones with the largest first element e.g. `[[10,1,3,6],[2,1,4,7]] -> [10,1,3,6]`

I've been trying to come to a solution using nested loops and a second list to take the elements I want to keep, but I can't seem to be able to nail it.

Is there an elegant solution I could use?

Comment: In your first case, the list does not have 4th subelement equal to 0.

Comment: I don't know what your exact solution is, but I have a feeling [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) will help.

Comment: No you didn't. There is no element with the 4th item equal to 0 in your original list.

Answer (score 2):

If listA is your original list, and listB is your new list, it seems like part (2) could be solved by iterating through listA, checking if the current element (nested list) contains a duplicate second element, and if it does, comparing the first elements to see which nested list stays in listB.  So in pseudo-code:

```
sizeOfListA = # whatever the original size is
sizeOfListB = 0

for i in (sizeOfListA):
  for j in (sizeOfListB):
    if listA[i][1] == listB[j][1]:  # check if second element is a duplicate
      if listA[i][0] > listB[j][0]: # check which has the bigger first element
        listB[j] = listA[i]
    else:   # if second element is unique, append nested list and increment size
      listB.append(listA[i])
      sizeOfListB += 1
```

That's only for part (2).  Like Burhan's comment, I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this, but I think this would get the job done.  Also, the question doesn't say what happens when the first elements are equal, so that would need to be accounted for too.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter as ig

data = [[10,1,3,6],[22,3,5,7],[2,1,4,7],[44,3,1,0]]

# filter and sort by main key
valid_sorted = sorted((el for el in data if el[3] != 0), key=ig(1))
# ensure identical keys have highest first element first
valid_sorted.sort(key=ig(0), reverse=True)
# group by second element
grouped = groupby(valid_sorted, ig(1))
# take first element for each key
selected = [next(item) for group, item in grouped]
print selected
# [[22, 3, 5, 7], [10, 1, 3, 6]]
```

Or using a `dict`:

```
d = {}
for el in valid_sorted: # doesn't need to be sorted - just excluding 4th == 0
    d[el[1]] = max(d.get(el[1], []), el)
print d.values()
# [[10, 1, 3, 6], [22, 3, 5, 7]]
```

Comment: Now that I'm re-visiting my code...do we need sorted? Isn't its result nullified by the following sort?

Comment: There isn't a "following sort" - could you explain?

Comment: Well, valid_sorted is constructing by sorting the elements of the "data" list not having a 0 as a fourth number, according to the specified key. The next sort is done in place, according to a different key, in reverse order. I must be missing something, but aren't we sorting the already sorted (in the previous step) list, according to a different key? It kind of seems to me that result would be the same if I had used key=ig(0), reverse = True in the sorted statement, while skipping the sort statement completely. I may be wrong and the sort may be sorting on a 2nd level.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the ordering of the final list, you can sort by the second item and use a generator to find the maximum for the first:

```
l = [[10,1,3,6],[22,3,5,7],[2,1,4,7],[44,3,1,0]]

remove_zeros_in_last = filter(lambda x: x[3] != 0, l)

ordered_by_2nd = sorted(remove_zeros_in_last, key=lambda x: x[1])

def group_equal_2nd_by_largest_first(ll):
    maxel = None
    for el in ll:
        if maxel is None:
            maxel = el  # Start accumulating maximum
        elif el[1] != maxel[1]:
            yield maxel
            maxel = el
        elif el[0] > maxel[0]:
            maxel = el  # New maximum
    if maxel is not None:
        yield maxel     # Don't forget the last item!

print list(group_equal_2nd_by_largest_first(ordered_by_2nd))

# gives [[10, 1, 3, 6], [22, 3, 5, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for the second part:

```
from itertools import product

lis = [[10, 1, 3, 6], [22, 3, 5, 7], [2, 1, 4, 7]]
lis = set(map(tuple, lis))   #create a set of items of lis
removed = set()             #it will store the items to be removed

for x, y in product(lis, repeat=2):
    if x != y:
        if x[1] == y[1]:
            removed.add(y if x[0] > y[0] else x)

print "removed-->",removed

print lis-removed       #final answer
```

**output:**

```
removed--> set([(2, 1, 4, 7)])
set([(22, 3, 5, 7), (10, 1, 3, 6)])
```